# Extract all matches with a specific pattern in DuckDB

Tags: postgresql, duckdb

I am trying to translate a query from Postgres to DuckDB that does the following: for a given string the query returns

1. All numbers
2. All pairs of consecutive tokens

The original Postgres queries are:

1. `select (regexp_matches('34 121 adelaide st melbourne 3000', '[\d]+', 'g'))[1];`
2. `select  (regexp_matches ( '34 121 adelaide st melbourne 3000', '[a-z0-9]+ [a-z0-9]+', 'g' ))[1] union select (regexp_matches ( regexp_replace ( '34 121 adelaide st melbourne 3000', '[a-z0-9]+', '' ),  '[a-z0-9]+ [a-z0-9]+', 'g' ))[1];`

For example, given the string '34 121 adelaide st melbourne 3000':

1. Return a table with row values 34, 121, 3000
2. Return a table with row values '34 121', '121 adelaide', 'adelaide st', 'st melbourne', 'melbourne 3000']

Using the regexp_extract function I can only return the first match. E.g.,
`select regexp_extract('34 121 adelaide st melbourne 3000', '[\d]+');`
produces '34' but none of the other digits.
Similarly `select regexp_extract('34 121 adelaide st melbourne 3000', '[a-z0-9]+ [a-z0-9]+');` produces '34 121'

The second query I can re-write using a join to produce the correct results (although I would still prefer to do this in a simpler way).

Would anyone be able to assist?

I tried `select regexp_extract('34 121 adelaide st melbourne 3000', '[\d]+');' which results in a table containing only '34' and none of the other numbers.

Comment: Looks like I can extract all the numeric values as follows:
`with tokens as 
(
select 1 addr_id,
unnest(string_to_array('34 121 adelaide st melbourne 3000', ' ')) as token
)
select addr_id, array_agg(token) from tokens
where regexp_matches(token, '[0-9]+')
group by addr_id;'

But would still be interested to know if this can be done in a similar way to Postgres

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.